# In Xcode, is it okay to adjust the view hierarchy by dragging in the outline view?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I am developing an iOS app, using Xcode. In Xcode's built-in Interface Builder, there is an area displaying my views and its subviews. This area is called "outline view" by Apple. It seems that I can adjust the view hierarchy of the subviews by dragging in the outline view. So, is it okay to do this? Does it have any other effect? I tried to search for the answer in Apple's documentation but didn't find an exact answer. Can anyone tells where I can see the exact description of the outline view in Apple's documentation?

Answer (score 1):

yes its ok to do so, in fact thats one of its purposes, the only effect it can have is that it will break most of your autolayouts attached to that view, so would just need to re-add them (only when moving out of a parent view, if its within the same view it will be fine). it also affects the draw order of subviews